# Filter date , decimal using ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, decimal, filtering

May I know if it is possible to filter fields that are in date or decimal? If yes , could i have some examples? I am trying to do an app which have search function for the release date and price using asp.net, any way on how to do this? Thank you. 
To search string , I had used :

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitle))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchTitle));
            }
```

But how do i do it for date that was in datepicker and price which is in decimal. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean filter in date or decimal. Can you please explain what you actually require?

Comment: I have a search feature where user would be able to search the release date of the movie and they could also search using the price of the movie which is in decimal form. Hence , may i know if this is do able?

Comment: Yes it is. Now in what context do you want to filter them: From a database? In a data structure? Client side? Please take the Stack Overflow tour. You will see that it is off toptic to ask for off-site links and that your question is very broad and very vague. Once you have some code where you are having trouble with filtering, feel free to ask about that problem.

Comment: From a database . Client side

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a function that returns a list of `movie` objects. It will take a List of `Movies` parameter for original list, the `string` parameter for Title, nullable `DateTime` for release date and nullable Decimal for price. I will assume that is a cumulative filter: i.e. "and"

If null or an empty string is passed as a parameter, it will be ignored. The title filter will not be case sensitive.

```
public List<movie> FilterMovies(List<movie> sourceList, string Title, DateTime? ReleaseDate, Decimal? Price)
{
     return movies.Where(
                  (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) || m => m.Title.ToLower().Contains(Title.ToLower()) &&
                  (!ReleaseDate.HasValue) || m.ReleaseDate == ReleaseDate.Value) &&
                  (!Price.HasValue) || m.Price == Price)
              ).ToList();
}
```

This is untested and done from memory and is a guess at best because I have no idea of what your `movie` object/model is like. I will also leave it up to you to get the correctly typed information from user input as we have little information to go on there.